# How to pass a relative range as argument on button click

Tags: excel, vba

I want to set up a button that will, on click send a range as argument to the method it calls. The range would be relative to the placement of the button, as shown here:

[image: Example 1]

I cannot use absolute coordinates (as 'E5' in this example) because the button will be inserted dynamically in locations I cannot guess.

In the context of this work, some button may share the same name, which prevents me from just using `Set button = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller)` in the receiving sub (not that it would crash, but it may refer to the wrong button instead of the real caller, which can only be fixed by modifying the name of the button).

So here I am, wondering if this is even possible. If not, I will have to write a method to make every button name unique, which would work (I did it in another project), but I am trying to avoid this as it will prevent me from using button names as absolute identifiers, as in a switch for example.

Comment: I have kind of similar scenarios too, I'm not quite sure why buttons will give you that problem, what I use are shapes `With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)` and a "handler" sub (or in yout case I'd think of a function) that all of them point to, in that sense you could get the range out of the object. However note that relying on ranges that can be dynamic instead of setting a proper name for the object (shape, button,etc) may be more risky.

Comment: As the button may be inserted more than once on the same sheet, several buttons may share the same name, which `Application.Caller` doesn't deal with very well. I had issues with this in the past where a button would make the call and the modification would be applied to another button with the same name. Do you mean that you had better results with non-unique names because they were linked from 'Shapes' instead of 'Buttons' ??

Comment: "some button may share the same name" - on purpose, or accidentally?

Comment: @TimWilliams On purpose, my 'plan B' is to make those names unique but it comes at a cost with other operations, so I'm validating if avoiding this is feasible.

Comment: You can give your buttons common prefixes, with a random/incrementing suffix.  eg "Button1_123", "Button1_345"  and deal with that accordingly.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for the tip. I automated this logic in another project with good results. I am looking into an alternative method with different plus and minus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out: in my short testing seems to work OK.

I put some shapes on a worksheet (some with the same name) and assigned the sub `Shape_Click` to all of them. Clicking any shape (even one of those sharing a common name) reliably highlights the clicked-on shape.

See [Excel VBA Code: Compile Error in x64 Version ('PtrSafe' attribute required)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16763147/excel-vba-code-compile-error-in-x64-version-ptrsafe-attribute-required) about API declarations and 32- vs 64-bit VBA.

```vb
Option Explicit

Declare PtrSafe Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long

Type POINTAPI
    x As Long
    y As Long
End Type

Sub Shape_Click()
    Dim point As POINTAPI, obj As Object
    
    GetCursorPos point
    On Error Resume Next 'ignore error if problem
    Set obj = ActiveWindow.RangeFromPoint(point.x, point.y)
    On Error GoTo 0
    'Highlight the clicked object (for demo purposes...)
    If Not obj Is Nothing Then Highlight obj 
    'Do something useful with obj...
    
End Sub

'color `obj` differently from other shapes on the same sheet
Sub Highlight(obj As Object)
    Dim shp, match
    For Each shp In obj.Parent.Shapes
        'assuming no superimposed shapes...
        match = (shp.Left = obj.Left And shp.Top = obj.Top)
        shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = IIf(match, vbBlue, vbRed)
        DoEvents
    Next shp
End Sub
```

Comment: Clever idea, though it didn't work on my end. I'm not that experimented with VBA, could you add some details about your methodology so I can reproduce your results?

Comment: See my edits above.  If those don't resolve it then a bit more detail around "didn't work" would be useful.